# preventing datetime field overflow exception

Tags: java, jdbc

I am developing a java program for transferring a Microsoft access 2010 database from one schema to another.  I am noticing that about 3% of the records contain invalid dates, which are throwing DateTime field overflow exceptions.

How can I write a test for Date values that converts any invalid date to null BEFORE it is able to trigger a DateTime field overflow exception?

Here is an example of a line of code that triggers the exception:

```
try {ps6.setDate(4, myDate);} catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Here is an example of an invalid value of the myDate variable which throws the exception:

```
0151-06-25
```

And here is the stack trace for the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Datetime field overflow
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3156)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:215)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:137)
    at pic_data.test.MigrateDataTools.migratePICIntakeTable(MigrateDataTools.java:1007)
    at pic_data.test.MigrateDataTools.main(MigrateDataTools.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, is 0151-06-25 is not an invalid date, so running it through joda-time and SimpleDateFormat and javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime won't die.
You can, however, check for boundary conditions (like really old years) that are particular to your use case (and JDBC driver) before you call the update statement that is throwing the exception.

```
Calendar c7= javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("0151-06-25");
Date d4 = c7.getTime();
int year = c7.get( Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println("d4: " + d4 + "; year: " + year);
```

If the year or any other component looks bad, then set the date to NULL before setting it into your prepared statement.